# How to correctly use a JPA EntityManager in playframework 2.4+

Tags: java, scala, jpa, web, playframework

The documentation for using JPA in playframework is rather sparse. 
All there is, from the following page, 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaJPA
is a simple example of a `persistence.xml` and other basic configurations that must be done before it can be used at all. 
However, how to use the `EntityManager`, is not very details.

In various examples on the web, I've come across three ways to get at an `EntityManager`:

1. `JPA.em()`
2. `JPA.em(String key)`
3. 

```
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("defaultPersistenceUnit");
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    // where the string 'defaultPersistenceUnit' corresponds to the persistence-unit name in my persistence.xml file.
```

If I use JPA as play seems to intend, I

1. have a `@Transactional` annotated method in a controller  // must be in the controller)
2. grab the `EntityManager` instance from `JPA.em()` // not the other method which takes String key. That's the wrong one!
3. perform my operation. End.

OK. That works fine.

```
@Transactional
public Result addPerson()
{
    Person person = Form.form(Person.class).bindFromRequest().get();

    EntityManager em = JPA.em();
    persist(em, person); // 'persist' is my static helper method

    return redirect(routes.Application.index());
}
```

However, I'd like to understand the;

1. life of an `EntityManager`
2. What `EntityManager` is used when I do `JPA.em()`
3. What `EntityManager` is used when I do `JPA.em("default")`
   // "default" seems to be so far the only key that works with this...
4. What `EntityManager` is used when I do

```
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("defaultPersistenceUnit");
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

5. Why doesn't the key used in both methods from 3 and 4 correspond?

The documentation for the class JPA specifies
`public static javax.persistence.EntityManager em(java.lang.String key)`
Get the EntityManager for specified persistence unit for this thread.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/index.html

So I would have assumed that key would/could/should correspond to the value of the name attribute of the persistence-unit element (in persistence.xml).
i.e.,

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <!-- can be create/validate/update/create-drop -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

So, while I have this working, it still feels a bit like magic. I guess I have to debug the Play code itself? So long as I stick to initiating the transaction from the controller only (as evidently intended) I guess I should have no problems.... with the life-cycle of the `EntityManager`... with cleaning up database resources etc.

But I guess there could be situations coming up where I need an `EntityManager` in some other context?

Then what do I use?
What is the best-practice life of an `EntityManager` in the context of a Playframework (or otherwise) web application? 
The life of a request? The life of the application? Or something dynamically in between? What is playframework doing with its own managed `EntityManager`?

Comment: Ok, in further testing of my demo app, I notice that a new EntityManager is used for each request. That is reassuring, as others seem to mention that the EntityManager is not threadsafe.  - 
see answer from user35736644892 - : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166218/how-to-manage-entitymanager-life-cycle-in-cdi-environement-using-tomcat